# Move carousel by dragging the scrollbar holder in Touch Carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm using Touch Carousel.

Is there any way to make the scroll bar holder draggable? So that the user can drag the holder as well instead of the carousel's content only.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this Slider with draggable scrollbar implementation: 
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/plugins/scrollbar.php